# Ошибка при input (Python)

Tags: python

Из-за чего может быть "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file." при input?..

```
    answer = input()
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

input находится внутри функции. Хоть в самом начале, всё равно возникает эта ошибка.

В коде нет ни одного open или with, зато есть pyautogui, keyboard, time, PIL. Просто не знаю, из-за чего ещё это может быть.
Из кода не знаю что прикрепить - input никак не изменяется в программе.

Comment: Ну тогда хотя бы приведите **полный стек-трейс** ошибки, а не только то, что вы посчитали из него важным. Даже если там много строк - **приведите их все**. Добавьте эту информацию в вопрос. Форматирование используйте такое же как для кода. Если не разберётесь с форматированием, мы поможем. Но без информации советовать нечего будет. Хотя возможно и стек-трейса будет мало, всё-равно нужен будет код.

Comment: Либо сбой интерпретатора (перегрузите компьютер), либо, скорее, вы что-то путаете. ` answer = input()` такую ошибку не должен вызывать. И да, давайте полный  стек-трейс, разумеется. А лучше приведите к  нему минимальный воспроизводимый пример (убирайте части кода до тех пор, пока ошибка не исчезнет - так и саму часть, его вызывающую, найдете).

Comment: Нашпигуйте вашу программу диагностикой `assert not sys.stdin.closed` и отследите момент когда закрывается входной поток.

Answer (score 3):

Простейший пример, который удовлетворяет всем требованиям вопроса, за исключением импорта лишних пакетов:

> input находится внутри функции. ...
>
> В коде нет ни одного open или with, зато есть pyautogui, keyboard,
> time, PIL. Просто не знаю, из-за чего ещё это может быть. Из кода не
> знаю что прикрепить - input никак не изменяется в программе.

```
import sys


def f():
    input()


sys.stdin.close()
f()
```

> ```
> $ python temp.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/sv/desk/stackoverflow/temp.py", line 9, in <module>
>     f()
>   File "/home/sv/desk/stackoverflow/temp.py", line 5, in f
>     input()
> ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
> ```

**P.S.** Смысл этого ответа - показать что отладиться и привести нужный минимальный пример - вполне подъёмная задача.

Comment: В Google Colab, кстати, без ошибок отрабатывает. Ну там весь ввод-вывод перепиленный )

Comment: @CrazyElf, `import keyboard` намекает что это десктопный CPython. :)

Comment: Кстати, какой в вашем случае стек-трейс получается? )

Comment: @CrazyElf, добавил стек в ответ.